# How to replace &#39; with ' in bixby

Tags: javascript, bixby, bixbystudio

[image: screenshot]

How can Replace `&#39;` with an Apostrophe `'` in Bixby?
I am new to Bixby studio. So please help.

```
var http = require('http');
var console = require('console');
var config = require('config');
var base64 = require('base64');

module.exports.function = function FindRecipes(type) {
    console.log("FindRecipe filter by a specific type");
    var options = {
        format: 'json', query: { search: type }
    };

    var response = http.getUrl(config.get('remote.url'), options);

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file for your Bixby project is Javascript.

So you can use the [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function (I am assume `response` is a String).

Use the `g` flag in the regex to replace more than one instance of the string.

```js
return response.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
```

**Edit:**

To fix the encoding on all properties since `response` is an object.

```js
for (var prop in response) {
  response[prop] = response[prop].replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
}
```

Comment: {"id":"","source":"","qsource":"","duration":"","servings":"","calories":"","favcount":"","ingredients":"","directions":""}

this is my response (json)

Comment: @NithinPMolethu Is the `response` an object or a string? I know it's json, but is it already parsed? I had edited my answer, try it